# Synchronising two select boxes in jQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have to `<select>` lists. The first is populated from my database. When the first `<select>` is changed, I want the second `<select>` to be populated with the same values as the first, *excluding* the selected option.

Can anyone explain to me how I can do this in jQuery?

Below is the code I have already; but I'm unsure how to bind the second `<select>` in the `else` condition.

```
$(document).ready($(function () {
    $('Ddl_Buyer').change(function () {
        var selected = $(this).val();
        if (selected == 'select') {

        } else {
            if ($(this).val() == selected) $('#ddl_Seller option[value="' + selected + '"]').remove();
        }
    });
}));
```

Comment: Please tag your question with WebForms, if applicable.

Comment: Can we see some code you have till now.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#Ddl_Buyer').change(function() {
    var selected = $(this).val();
    $('#ddl_Seller').empty();
    $("#Ddl_Buyer option").each(function(){
        $('#ddl_Seller').append($(this).clone());
    });
    $('#ddl_Seller option[value="' + selected + '"]').remove();
});
```

See the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CTdwk/

Comment: @shwetachauhan Glad to help! Please accept the answer if you got your problem solved.